# Change color of every div element with the same id which is equals some text

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to change the background color of each div element with the same id that is equals some specific text. Code below is working only for the first div in my code. How can I apply this for every div with the same id and specific text inside.

Ok. I Understand that the Id needs to be unique. Could you please help me to do this with classes?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myDIV">
 Hello
</div>


<div id="myDIV">
 Hello
</div>

<script>

if (document.getElementById('myDIV').innerHTML.indexOf("Hello") != -1) {
document.getElementById('myDIV').style.backgroundColor='blue';
} 
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Id's should be unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, id must be unique.

```
var targets = document.getElementsByClassName('myDIV');
for( var i in targets ) {
    if (targets[i].innerHTML.indexOf("Hello") != -1) {
        targets[i].className='myDIV blue';
    }  
};
```

Then add the color in your styles:

```
.blue { background-color: blue; }
```

Here's a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/mckinleymedia/5nj7yw2e/1/

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have same id multiple times in same web page. use class instead.

Use class for that.

```
<div class="myDIV">
     Hello
</div>


<div class="myDIV">
     Hello
</div>
```

Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tRqBV/348/)

Comment: Ok. But I don´t know how to apply javascript on each class.

Comment: This doesn't answer his question

Comment: @Mr.Alien i was preparing the fiddle for this.

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju You should post the code here, if jsfiddle shuts down or link gets 403, your answer won't be useful for future visitors

Answer (score 1):

Try with classes:

```
<div id="myDIV1" class="myDIV">
 Hello
</div>
<div id="myDIV2" class="myDIV">
 Hello
</div>
```

JS:

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName( "myDIV" );
for( var i = 0; i < x.length; i++ ) {
    x[i].style.backgroundColor='blue';
}
```

On jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/ppd891xb/

Answer (score 0):

The id must be unique. You can use class instead of id. According to [W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute):

> The id attribute specifies its element's unique identifier (ID). 
>   The value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home subtree and must contain at least one character. The value must not contain any space characters.

Comment: w3schools is not a decent website to provide a source for, w3 source will be much more useful.

Comment: Your script part should not work as the getElementsByClassName returns an array-like object.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to share this with you.
The code above doesn't work for me cause I'd like to change class name instead changing attributes.

I have a calendar with one ID for each day and a class name for each type of mark. This is, p. ex. a holiday day, then its class name is 'holiday'. If i didn't go to work in 2 weeks, then those 14 days have a class name like 'ausenciasDias'. My intention is they must be off and when mouse over in a button they must show or be on.

If I run:

```
("#button").on('click', function () {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName( "ausenciasDias_off" );
    for( var i = 0; i < x.length; i++ ) {
        x[i].className = "ausenciasDias_on";
    }
});
```

Then only few `<td class="ausenciasDias_off">` turn on.
Tracing code I found out that index of "i" is wrong, due when a class name change index point to next td.
To solve this, I use the code below:

```
var targets = document.getElementsByClassName("diasAusencia_off");
var tamaño = targets.length;       
for (var i=0; i<tamaño; i++) {        
    var element = targets[0];
    element.className = "diasAusencia_on";
};
```

I hope it helps someone.
Regards.